# Find the position function from the piecewise-defined velocity function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I am getting stuck on a position function problem in my Diff Eq class.  Problem 22 is shown on the right in the picture below.  On the left is the answer.  My work below shows that I get stuck calculating the second interval 3 geq t leq 7.  It looks like the initial position is supposed to be negative and I calculate it as positive?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/a7QQ2.jpg

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jg0az.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint to get you started:  Since $x(0)=0$,

$x(t)=x(t)-x(0)=\int_0^t v(t)dt\;\;$ where $v(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{5}{3}t &\mbox{, if } 0\le t\le3\\5 &\mbox{, if }3\le t\le 7\\-\frac{5}{3}t+\frac{50}{3} &\mbox{, if } 7\le t\le10\end{cases}$

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I haven't been able to crack it just yet, though.  Perhaps I should try again in the morning.  I  am sure I am just missing something simple!

Comment: @user3032623 If you have more questions about solving it, let me know.

Comment: Sure.  I could use some more info.  I did get the answer in the end, but I am not sure I did it the best way possible.  In particular, getting the starting position seemed cumbersome.  Here is what I did: https://goo.gl/photos/xz5hNMGWsNFc5H2MA